# Constructing a specific polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need to construct a polynomial with zeroes at $3$, $5$, and $10$ (and the function can't just be tangent at those points, it has to go below/above the axis. Also, there can't be any zeroes in between these points) and with an $y$-intercept at 200. However, this is the tricky part: the polynomial also has to be greater than $200$ somewhere between $5$ and $10$. I know it has to be of the form
$$a(x-3)(x-5)(x-10)(x-p_1)(x-p_2)\cdots$$
but I'm starting to think this is impossible because since
$$a(3)(5)(10)(p_1)(p_2)\cdots =200$$
 so $a$ and the product of the roots are inversely proportional. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're on the right track.  Try throwing in a term like $(x^2+M)$ for some large $M$ to get the peak you want between $5$ and $10$.  This should take the place of your $(x-p_1)(x-p_2)\ldots$.  The term $(x^2+M)$ won't add any real zeroes.  After this, adjust your leading coefficient $a$ to give the desired $y$-intercept.

Comment: It's not that I can't add any more roots at all, it's just that I can't add them on the interval [0, 10]. I tried what you said before and as you increase M, you decrease a in order to get the product to be 200, and since you decrease a proportionally to how much you increase M, you don't seem to ever get the polynomial to reach 200 between (5, 10). This is why I didn't know how to do it.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. I just added an (x+1) factor. This increased the value of the dunction enough while keeping a constant.

Comment: Check out [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) for a more general answer to your question.  In general, we can find a polynomial that fits just about any points we want, so long as each $x$ value has exactly one $y$ value.

Comment: @Jared: The requirement that any additional roots must be _outside_ the $[0,10]$ interval means that it's not quite a run-of-the-mill polynomial interpolation problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do: Decide that your polynomial is going to be $f(x)=A(x-3)(x-5)(x-10)(x-R)$ for some $R$ and $A$. Start by temporarily setting $A=-1$.

If you now you choose $R$ as a small enough *negative* number, $f(7)$ will eventually be larger than $f(0)$ (because as $R\to 0$, we have $f(0)\to 0$ but $f(7)\to 168$). Once you find such an $R$, adjust the $A$ factor to get $f(0)=200$, and $f(7)$ will then automatically be larger than $200$

Comment: Thanks, even (x+1) was good enough of a factor to satisfy the conditions.